# How to programatically exit from an editor in Linux

Tags: cron

I am trying to configure a crontab from a .sh file. When this script will run on the server it should do the configuration. But when I try to edit the crontab by command "crontab -e" it doesn't come out of the editor. I am not getting which command I can write in my shell script file so that it will allow to write in the editor and then exit from editor.

My code to configure crontab is follows

```
crontab -e
echo "* * * * * run-parts /maven/abc.sh" 
crond /maven/logs/log.txt
```

Comment: Would you consider a change to your workflow where you put the desired contents into a file can call `crontab /that/file`?

Comment: I am creating a script file to do the configuration as we cannot ssh into the container. Can you provide example of what you are suggesting?